# Dell firmware update requires boot partition expansion

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi, dell, firmware

In 2016 I bought a Dell XPS 13 9350, which came with Ubuntu 14.04 out of the box. By now it has been upgraded to 20.04. Firmware updates are available from the Software Centre by default.

Lately, however, firmware updates are no longer installing. I found out out that the problem might be the size of the EFI boot partition, which is only 48 MB, supposedly too small for the firmware updates, according to the error message of the Software Centre.

What would be the safest way to continue? Resizing partitions which are at the beginning of the disk is notoriously risky. Attached is a picture of the partition (from GParted)

[image]

Comment: What is in p2? Is that a bootable image of the original 14.04 for recovery purposes? If so not very useful. I would back it up and erase it. Also ESP - efi system partitions are now FAT32. I might copy everything in p1 to p2 (after p2 housecleaned) and make it the ESP. You will still have to reinstall grub or use efibootmgr to create correct entry in UEFI as partUUID/GUID of ESP has changed. Good backups of entire system important before any major change.

Comment: Mounted p2 and that is indeed what it looks like (structured like a Linux filesystem). I might try your proposal to reuse that partition.